# Getting Undefined Undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the data attribute for an image so that it adds each data attribute (product name & price) to a table row when the image is over an specific container. I get undefined instead of each attribute value. All I can find is different ways to get the attribute ( .data("productname") / attr("data-productname"), but it doesn't do anything. I was able to go from undefined to object object writing .attr("data" , "productname"), but that's it.

```js
var dentro = 0;
    var productname = $(this).attr('data-productname');
    var price = $(this).attr('data-price');
    var row = "<tr><td>"+productname+"</td><td>"+price+"</td>"

    $("div#productcontainer img").draggable();
    $("#dropoutspiral").droppable({
    tolerance: "fit",


    drop : function(e){
        // $(".ui-draggable-dragging").effect("shake","slow");
        $(".ui-draggable-dragging").animate({
            "width": "0px",
            "height": "0px"
            }, { queue: false }, 1000, 
            function(){
                // $("table tbody").append(row);
                //alert("animacion comnpletada");
            });
        $(".ui-draggable-dragging").animate({
            opacity: 0,
        }, { queue: false }, 1000);
    },

    over : function(e){
        $("table tbody").append(row);

    }

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.min.js">
</script>
<div id="globalcontainer">
    <div id="dropoutspiral">
        <img class="absolute" src="img/spiral-comp.gif">
    </div>

    <div id="productcontainer">
        <img data-productname="manzana" data-price="10" src="img/manzana.jpg">
        <img data-productname="piña" data-price="50" src="img/pina.jpg">
        <img data-productname="uvas" data-price="80" src="img/uvas.jpg">
        <img data-productname="reloj" data-price="2000" src="img/watch.jpg">
    </div>

    <div id="table">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <td>PRODUCTO</td>
                <td>PRECIO</td>
            </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </div>

</div>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: What calls the JS shown? You're using `$(this).attr('data-productname');`, but what is `this`? If the code is inside an event handler bound specifically to the img elements then it should work, otherwise it will not work.

Comment: @Anil - There's no point converting the code to a runnable snippet if running it produces an error due to missing library file(s) unrelated to the behaviour the question is asking about.

Comment: @nnnnnn, thanks for pointing out, included the jquery UI.

Comment: @nnnnnn *this* would be the element being dropped.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use UI element of drop event, refer updated drop event in below.

```
drop : function(e,ui){
var productname = $(ui.draggable).attr('data-productname');
      var price = $(ui.draggable).attr('data-price');
```

`$(this)` represents the droppable (your box). 
`ui.draggable` represents the draggable, the element your are dropping.

```js
var dentro = 0;
   

    $("div#productcontainer img").draggable();
    $("#dropoutspiral").droppable({
    tolerance: "fit",


    drop : function(e,ui){
    if($(this).attr('id')  == 'dropoutspiral') {
      var productname = $(ui.draggable).attr('data-productname');
      var price = $(ui.draggable).attr('data-price');
      var row = "<tr><td>"+productname+"</td><td>"+price+"</td>"
      alert(productname);
        $("table tbody").append(row); }

        $(".ui-draggable-dragging").animate({
            "width": "0px",
            "height": "0px"
            }, { queue: false }, 1000, 
            function(){
               
              
            });
        $(".ui-draggable-dragging").animate({
            opacity: 0,
        }, { queue: false }, 1000);
    },

    over : function(e){
  

    }

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.min.js">
</script>
<div id="globalcontainer">
    <div id="dropoutspiral">
        <img class="absolute" src="https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">
    </div>

    <div id="productcontainer">
        <img data-productname="manzana" data-price="10" src="img/manzana.jpg">
        <img data-productname="piña" data-price="50" src="img/pina.jpg">
        <img data-productname="uvas" data-price="80" src="img/uvas.jpg">
        <img data-productname="reloj" data-price="2000" src="img/watch.jpg">
    </div>

    <div id="table">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <td>PRODUCTO</td>
                <td>PRECIO</td>
            </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I do have a question though. Why does it work only when the variables are inside the If(){}, adding the ui.draggable without ' ' ? Shouldn't it work if the variables are outside everything?

Comment: Also tried removing the IF from the drop, and it is working. Still, i don't get why the variables must be inside drop

Comment: if is for requirement :add to a table when drop on a particular box". in case of drop anywhere else your table should not be populated.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below code to pull out the attributes.

Script :

```js
$(function() {
    $('#productcontainer').children('img').each(function () {
       $("#datadiv").append("<div>"+$(this).data('productname')+" | "+$(this).data('price')+"</div>"); // "this" is the current element in the loop
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

   <div id="productcontainer">
        <img data-productname="manzana" data-price="10" src="img/manzana.jpg">
        <img data-productname="piña" data-price="50" src="img/pina.jpg">
        <img data-productname="uvas" data-price="80" src="img/uvas.jpg">
        <img data-productname="reloj" data-price="2000" src="img/watch.jpg">
    </div>
    <div id="datadiv">
        <div><span> Name </span> | <span> Price </span></div>
    </div>
```

jsfiddle :

https://jsfiddle.net/b1mLbygk/1/